# Performing facebook Oauth from my App in android studio 1.5.1

Tags: android

hi am new to this oauth and here i have some tired code to log in facebook from my app.. but my onError method is being called.. can anyone help me to complete this app.. and i have properly configured my manifest, gradle and have generated hash key using openssl tool..

Here is my code:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private LoginButton fbLoginButton;
public CallbackManager callbackManager;
public String facebook_accessToken;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    fbLoginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.facebook_sign_in_button);
    fbLoginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile","email"));

    fbLoginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                    try {
                        String email = object.getString("email");
                        Log.i("Email form FB: ", email);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.getMessage();
                    }
                }
            });

            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            facebook_accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken().toString();

            Log.i("Facebook Name..", loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId());

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "User cancelled facebook login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    });
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.i("I am in..", "Activity Result");
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}}
```

Comment: Log.e("facebook error",error.toString()); and post this error

Comment: its not going into my void onError() method.

Comment: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED this is the error am getting in my onError()

Comment: Where r u running this app. on your phone or emulator

Comment: am running this in emulator.. i guess there is some problem in my emulator.

Answer (score 0):

net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED means there may be broken internet connection. To check that you must take a browser in the emulator and check it. If no internet connection found please create another emulator